# Can I change the name of "hibernate.properties"? where it is picked up?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm

I'm aware, that the `hibernate.cfg.xml` is the default configuration resource name if/when invoking `configure()` on the `Configuration` instance, as `configure()` uses `StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.DEFAULT_CFG_RESOURCE_NAME`'s hardcoded value for the name of the file to be consumed.

I'm also aware, that I can use overloaded `.configure(String)` should I want to customize the configuration resource name.

What I cannot find is the similar moment for `hibernate.properties` - where it is hardcoded or consumed.. I thought this information could help me to determine whether I can change `.properties` name or not. Can I? or it's some deeply hard-coded string, control over which, I can't obtain?

I was just thinking to demonstrate identicality of `.xml` and `.properties`.. as a lot of resources suggest `.properties` as an alternative approach to `.xml` (for configuring `org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration` instance).

But I, kind of, have a doubt now.. is it really an alternative (like JPA annotations are alternative for xml)? or it's some supplementary file (provided optionally), that can be consumed by `.xml`? as I also cannot find how (if I can) do I register mapping definitions in the `Configuration` instance, with the `.properties` file.

When I say, "I cannot find", I literally mean the Hibernate's reference documentation, which really seems incomplete, as it states:

> For Hibernate's configuration, we can use a simple hibernate.properties file, a **more
> sophisticated hibernate.cfg.xml file, or even complete programmatic setup.**

but it never explains anything more.. like how can I change file's name.. or how can I register mapping definitions, when it comes to `.properties` file.

Comment: Typically everything would be configured in `hibernate.cfg.xml`, there are probably use cases for mixing it with `hibernate.properties` though. What problem are you trying to solve with `hibernate.properties`?

Comment: @Guillaume read the 4th paragraph. I want to prove equivalence, or the opposite - that these two (.properties, .xml) are [not] interchangeable. In the simpler words: assume, I want to use `.properties` file for entire configuration (which, docs say, is possible).

Answer (score 0):

You can configure Hibernate with a properties object you have loaded or created yourself:

```
 InputStream stream = ...getResourceAsStream( "/my-hibernate.properties" );
 properties = new Properties();
 properties.load(stream);

 configuration.setProperties(properties);
```

or:

```
 configuration.addProperties(properties);
```

But it will look for the hard-coded `hibernate.properties` in [org.hibernate.cfg.Environment](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/8afce5b5ed72a8fa9e15fbaa608a5b2abb92e9de/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/cfg/Environment.java#L181)

As far as I know this is for settings such as database URL, password etc. but mappings need to be configured separately, either programmatically or through XML files